# Google Birthday Doodle Morse Code?

Tags: morse-code

Morse code in this doodle? think Interstellar (movie)

https://www.google.com/doodles/googles-23rd-birthday

Comment: This question provoked a [debate](https://ham.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/457/should-we-expand-the-scope-of-this-site-to-include-questions-about-morse-code) about whether or not questions about Morse code that have nothing to do with radio are within the scope of this site or not.  The current consensus is that we should allow such questions, *but* such questions should be objectively answerable, meaning that answers shouldn't be opinion-based, and a clear majority of people competent in Morse code should have no trouble coming to agreement on what the alleged Morse code is saying.

Comment: This question fails the "objectively answerable" test, and is therefore off-topic by current standards.  I believe that it should be left open because the new standards were not in place when the question was asked.  However, let's be clear that this question shouldn't be used as a precedent for future questions.  That is all!  :)

Answer (score 1):

Sadly I did not see any Morse code but that is a great idea!
Comment (since I'm not allowed to comment I will add it here):
I know it's the candle, I watched it in slow motion. It does not have Morse code because it is almost perfectly periodic and every now and then it has a slight glitch probably when the CPU or browser is busy with something else for a split second and a little late when updating the graphic.

Answer (score 1):

I think the OP is referring to the flickering of the candle in the animation.  That doesn't look like Morse code, unless the message is something like EEEEEEEEETEEEEIEEEEETEETEEEEEEAEEEEEE.  It's possible a message is encoded in there somehow, but if so the encoding isn't just Morse code.

Comment: notice the dots and dashes in the letters

Comment: There are dots and dashes in the letters, but the dots are with other dots and the dashes are with other dashes.  Morse code frequently mixes dots and dashes like this -- --- ·-· ··· ·   -·-· --- -·· ·

Comment: The dots in letter G could be interpreted as SHE or GHS depending on if you use the two dashes in the G and go in reverse order (GHS being Google Hosting Service). The dashes above could be used as guides for implied dashes in the bottom. Can you see other ways to interpret this?

Comment: I don't see it, but I'm not all that imaginative.  Could you whip up a graphic showing what you're talking about?